# What buffers are between commands in a pipeline?

Tags: linux, pipe, libc, piping

I thought it was 1 buffer, but now it occurs to me that it might be 2.

I mean in a pipeline:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

`cmd2`'s output might be e.g. line buffered and there is no pipeline there. This should be the buffer managed by libc `FILE *` stream functions like `fwrite()`, or is this buffer also used by `write(3)`? However, I just remembered that `pipe(7)` talks about the size of the pipe buffers that's apparently controlled in the kernel.

Is stdin buffered, too? Are there 3 buffers, 1 in kernel space and 2 in user space?

I previously thought that `read(2)` hung when a pipeline buffer was empty, but when stdin is not a pipe but rather a terminal, there i no pipeline buffer, right? If it doesn't have its own buffer, does it check different buffers depending on whether stdin is a pipe or a terminal or a regular file?

EDIT: Changed "how many" to "what" in the question. I hope that's not too big a change. I'm interested in knowing what the buffers are, not just a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is stdin buffered, too? Are there 3 buffers, 1 in kernel space and 2 in user space?

Yes, *in general* there could be 3 buffers here: one for `cmd1` `stdout`, one for `cmd2` `stdin`, and one in kernel space.

> I previously thought that `read(2)` hung when a pipeline buffer was empty, but when stdin is not a pipe but rather a terminal, there i no pipeline buffer, right?

The `read` system call blocks when there is no input, but that has *nothing* to do with `stdio` buffering.

The kernel buffer exists *regardless* of whether the input is from a terminal or not (it would be very inefficient for the kernel to transfer one character at a time).

By *default* the `stdio` library will not buffer terminal input, but the application can change that with explicit calls to e.g. [setvbuf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html).

A blog post with more details is [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/).